# Entry y aplicación de rangos con python

Tags: python, tkinter, validación, spyder

estoy trabajando con Tkinter en una app que pueda validar el contenido de las entradas (Entry). En este caso quisiera encontrar la forma para que en el "Entry" solo acepte un rango del 0 al 110.

En este ejemplo logré que solo aceptara valores numéricos, que me haría falta? Gracias

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.title('A. APP')
root.config(bg='deep sky blue')

def numero(char):
    return char in "0123456789"
validatecommand = root.register(numero)


root.config(width=300, height=200)

Entrada = ttk.Entry(root)
Etiqueta=ttk.Label(root)

Etiqueta = ttk.Label(text="Inserta edad valida")
Etiqueta.place(x=5, y=50)
Entrada = ttk.Entry(root,textvariable=Entrada, font=('Times', 14), width=5, validate="key", validatecommand=(validatecommand, "%S"))
Entrada.place(x=120, y=50)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Algunos consejos antes de decir como podrías hacerlo.

Antes de decirte como puedes hacerlo, debo de señalar algunas mejoras que pueden hacerse a tu código:

- Los str tienen un método llamado isdecimal, que devuelve True cuando una cadena está compuesta totalmente por numeros. Esto es muy util a la hora de que el usuario seleccione y borre una parte de lo escrito en el entry. Pues, si por ejemplo tienes escrito 1234 y el usuario intenta borrar 234, el valor de `char` va a ser 234.
- En esta linea `root.config(width=300, height=200)` la puedes cambiar por `root.geometry("300x200")`. Hace exactamente lo mismo. El método geometry acepta como primer argumento una cadena que será del formato [width]x[height].

---

Y señalaré un problema en tu código. Para mi esto es más importante que todo lo demás.

Vamos a analizar esta linea:

```
Entrada = ttk.Entry(root,textvariable=Entrada, font=('Times', 14), width=5, validate="key", validatecommand=(validatecommand, "%S"))
```

Cuando le pasas al entry el parametro textvariable, lo que le estas pasando es un Entry. Este no es el proposito de este parametro. Este parametro espera una variable de control (StringVar, IntVar, DoubleVar, etc).
Supongo que lo que querías hacer era pasar un StringVar.

---

Aplicando todo lo antes mencionado, tu código quedaría así:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.title('A. APP')
root.config(bg='deep sky blue')

def numero(char):
    # Usamos el método isdecimal para saber si la cadena char contiene solo numeros.
    return char.isdecimal()
validatecommand = root.register(numero)

# Usamos el método geometry para darle un tamaño a la ventana.
root.geometry("300x200")

# En lugar de crear un Entry, en esta linea creamos un StringVar que luego será asociado al entry.
variable_control = StringVar()
Etiqueta=ttk.Label(root)

Etiqueta = ttk.Label(text="Inserta edad valida")
Etiqueta.place(x=5, y=50)
Entrada = ttk.Entry(root,textvariable=variable_control, font=('Times', 14), width=5, validate="key", validatecommand=(validatecommand, "%S"))
Entrada.place(x=120, y=50)

root.mainloop()
```

#### Como puedes lograr lo que buscas.

Podrías usar el método trace de las variables de control para que se llame a una función cada vez que el usuario teclea algo.
Dentro de esa función puedes verificar constantemente que el usuario no se pase del limite establecido y si se pasa de dicho limite, establecer el valor del stringvar en dicho limite.
Por ejemplo, si el usuario ingresa 111 cuando el limite es 110, hacemos que el entry diga 110.

Aquí te dejo un código que hace eso mismo. Seguramente lo entiendas mejor viendo como funciona tu mismo.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.title('A. APP')
root.config(bg='deep sky blue')

def numero(char):
    # Usamos el método isdecimal para saber si la cadena char contiene solo numeros.
    return char.isdecimal()

def maxnumber(*args):
    maxnumber = 110

    # Obtengo lo que está escrito en el entry.
    contenido_entry = variable_control.get()
    
    # si hay algo escrito en el entry y dicho contenido es mayor a 110, entonces establecemos el contenido del entry en 110.
    if(contenido_entry and int(contenido_entry) > maxnumber):
        variable_control.set(maxnumber)

validatecommand = root.register(numero)

# Usamos el método geometry para darle un tamaño a la ventana.
root.geometry("300x200")

# En lugar de crear un Entry, en esta linea creamos un StringVar que luego será asociado al entry.
variable_control = StringVar()
Etiqueta=ttk.Label(root)

Etiqueta = ttk.Label(text="Inserta edad valida")
Etiqueta.place(x=5, y=50)
Entrada = ttk.Entry(root,textvariable=variable_control, font=('Times', 14), width=5, validate="key", validatecommand=(validatecommand, "%S"))
Entrada.place(x=120, y=50)

# Hacemos que cada vez que el contenido del entry cambie, se llame a la función maxnumber
variable_control.trace("w", maxnumber)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias hermano, si me has hecho ver que estaba usando unas cosas que había hecho mal. Gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

Para saber si un número está dentro de un rango, usa la función "range()" y el operador "in". Te recomiendo hacer lo siguiente:

```
def esNumero(char: str) -> bool:
    try:
        if not int(char) in range(110): return  False
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return True
```